# Arweave image urls broken for some collections with error GET request error `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Tags: nfts, arweave

Over the past week or so I've noticed that when I try displaying an NFT on my site using the image url found in the meta data, the image fails to load and the following error appears in the console for the get request: `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

This seems to be the case for a number of collections, even when viewing them on SolScan.
Here is the [Solana Money Girls collection](https://solscan.io/collection/a7d394f8c6355170b713d0f245713f3a39213e2c65d2685f82dcfe5cb7e28b9d) - None of the images are displayed.

Is anyone aware what might be causing this and how I can fix it to get the images to load on my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the likely cause. Since someone upvoted this question, I assume they might be having the same issue.

Strangely, this seems it might be an issue with my service provider.
I tried multiple browsers, all had the same issue. As soon as I switched to a VPN, all images loaded. I even tried a VPN based in my country and again all images loaded just fine. I suspect this must be down to my ISP doing some funny business. Still haven't figured out why some collections load and others don't.

**UPDATE (Working Solution):**

I found my ISP recently introduced "web safe" mode as part of their service. In my case, I logged in to my provider's website (NOT the router settings page) and from there I found a section called `Online security > Web Safe` and disabled the `Virus Safe` setting.

Hope this helps anyone facing similar issues.